# Record Live stream

Tags: streaming, rtmp

How do I record the live streaming screen with audio? I read in some forums about Mplayer and VLC player. I tried using download helper, with no luck

These are the steps I do

1. http://shalomtv.tv
2. Click and play shalom  India, the first tab, live television

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The stream in your link seems to be a RTMP stream. Solution:

## Downloading RTMP streams with rtmpdump and rtmpsrv

1. Install `rtmpdump` by opening your terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and using this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install rtmpdump
   ```
2. Redirect RTMP traffic through a local port. Copy & paste this command to the terminal window:

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1935 -j REDIRECT
   ```
3. Start `rtmpsrv` by typing in the terminal:

   ```
   rtmpsrv
   ```
4. Go to the website where the video stream is and start playing the video.
5. After a while, `rtmpsrv` should output a longish command that will look something like this:

   ```
   rtmpdump -r "rtmp://livestream.someaddress.com/live/" -a "live/" -f "LNX 11,6,602,171" -W "https://www.someaddress.org/live/player.swf" -p "http://live.tv/" -y "nnnnnn.sdp" -o nnnnnn.flv
   ```
6. Stop `rtmpsrv` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. You can leave the website.
7. *Before* downloading, you need to delete the port forwarding you did previously. Copy & paste this command to the terminal:

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1935 -j REDIRECT
   ```
8. Finally, copy the longish command starting with "rtmpdump -r..." and paste it in the terminal. `rtmpdump` should start downloading the stream. You can stop the downloading with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: @MadsSkjern: Edited answer. -A is append and -D is delete, so not permanently if you do the step 7.

Comment: It works, thx :) However, rtmpsrv also prints a few errors, which initially made me overlook the rtmpdump command. Are those errors expected?

Comment: @MadsSkjern I don't remember (haven't used rtmpdump in a while), but if the downloading itself works, I wouldn't care about the errors.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is newish, but this thing is brilliant:
`youtube-dl-bdmurray.youtube-dl`
It's a "snap", so to install it you type

`sudo snap install youtube-dl-bdmurray`

Then I simply wrote 
`youtube-dl-bdmurray.youtube-dl [url-containing-video]`

on the command line, and it found the video, started the video (which was not automatic), downloaded/streamed the thing, and left me with a perfect mp4 file.

Comment: It does not work with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gs4PyQ4uflo&ab_channel=BassYourLife .